# Loop and Concatenate in Excel using Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a way to create a calculated column using formula in Excel.

I want to calculate in my "Score" column, the number of empty columns in the row. And in my "EmptyLabels" concatenate the name of the empty columns.

Is there a way to do that in Excel without VBA and Macros ?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Excel sheet]

**UPDATE**
Try the IF and the ISBLANK for multiple columns can't be a solution. It gives me the error : can't handle multiple level of imbrication"

I have actually 50 Columns, and I think It cannot be done.
I t can works only for a little number of Columns and the right solution is Marked Below.

Comment: Try the IF and ISBLANK functions together with the [CONCATENATE function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/concatenate-function-870e82a1-d47d-440e-9a77-23e7639eda1d). Also the [COUNTBLANK function](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/countblank-function-c72134a2-695e-43ab-a3f3-714aa770f385).

Comment: Try the IF and the ISBLANK for multiple columns can't be a solution.
It gives me the error : can't handle multiple level of imbrication"

Comment: I tried For example the solution given by @Jeeped and, Actually I hove 50 Columns so it gives me that The file format cannot support all that arguments 
I think it reached the limit of caracters in the formula

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time @Jeeped
And thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The score is *' the number of empty columns in the row'* so that would make the [COUNTBLANK function](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/countblank-function-c72134a2-695e-43ab-a3f3-714aa770f385) formula in the first row,

```
=COUNTBLANK(Table1[@[Col 1]:[Col 7]])
```

The conditional concatenation can be handled by a series of nested IF and [ISBLANK](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-0F2D7971-6019-40A0-A171-F2D869135665) functions. Simple string concatenation is provided by the ampersand (e.g. `&`).

```
=TRIM(IF(ISBLANK([@[Col 1]]), Table1[[#Headers],[Col 1]]&" ", " ")&
      IF(ISBLANK([@[Col 2]]), Table1[[#Headers],[Col 2]]&" ", " ")&
      IF(ISBLANK([@[Col 3]]), Table1[[#Headers],[Col 3]]&" ", " ")&
      IF(ISBLANK([@[Col 4]]), Table1[[#Headers],[Col 4]]&" ", " ")&
      IF(ISBLANK([@[Col 5]]), Table1[[#Headers],[Col 5]]&" ", " ")&
      IF(ISBLANK([@[Col 6]]), Table1[[#Headers],[Col 6]]&" ", " ")&
      IF(ISBLANK([@[Col 7]]), Table1[[#Headers],[Col 7]]&" ", " "))
```

If you prefer the more formalized string stitching provided by the [CONCATENATE function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/concatenate-function-870e82a1-d47d-440e-9a77-23e7639eda1d) then,

```
=TRIM(CONCATENATE(IF(ISBLANK([@[Col 1]]), Table1[[#Headers],[Col 1]], ""), CHAR(32),
                  IF(ISBLANK([@[Col 2]]), Table1[[#Headers],[Col 2]], ""), CHAR(32),
                  IF(ISBLANK([@[Col 3]]), Table1[[#Headers],[Col 3]], ""), CHAR(32),
                  IF(ISBLANK([@[Col 4]]), Table1[[#Headers],[Col 4]], ""), CHAR(32),
                  IF(ISBLANK([@[Col 5]]), Table1[[#Headers],[Col 5]], ""), CHAR(32),
                  IF(ISBLANK([@[Col 6]]), Table1[[#Headers],[Col 6]], ""), CHAR(32),
                  IF(ISBLANK([@[Col 7]]), Table1[[#Headers],[Col 7]], "")))
```

[image: isblank_concat]

Comment: Thanks, 
It's a good solution but It gives me an error : "Actual File format cannot support all these arguments"
Because Actually I have 50 columns and I think the caracters in formula in Excel are limited

Answer (score 2):

Please try in H2:

```
=COUNTBLANK(A2:G2)
```

and in I2:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),A$1,"")&IF(ISBLANK(B2),B$1,"")&IF(ISBLANK(C2),C$1,"")&IF(ISBLANK(D2),D$1,"")&IF(ISBLANK(E2),E$1,"")&IF(ISBLANK(F2),F$1,"")&IF(ISBLANK(G2),G$1,"")
```

then copy both down to suit.

Answer (score -2):

If the columns could be variable, try something like

```
=COUNTA($A$2:OFFSET($H$2,0,-1))

=COLUMN()-$H2-2
```

and change $H to your scores column.

Comment: What does it do exactly ? It gives me a value "1" in all my column

Comment: I missed that you were starting in B2 not A1, so it should be as below, but it is not hard to work it out -
    =COUNTA($B3:OFFSET($I3,0,-1))   and   
    =COLUMN()-$I3-2

Comment: I'm cracking up, it's me that is starting in B2, not the OP.